# synchronize local and remote database

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have a requirement to synchronize local db data with multi users remote db, once the internet connection down we need to move working on the local db, once the connection is restored, the data should be synced with the remote db automatically.The sync is just usually data updates.
any available scenario how to do that

Comment: This sounds like a pretty advanced architecture.  Any reason why you have multiple DBs?  Would having one database, perhaps partitioned in some way, make your life easiser?

Comment: there is only ONE db - and there is multi users working on that database

Comment: Please add details about the local and remote database.  Are they the same?

Comment: just one database hosted online, both of us working on it, the internet connection down of my side so I will working on it on the local area, about your side you keep working on it online, once my Internet connection restored I need to sync it with the updates you made online